# How can I resolve the setState only accepts one argument when using Ink for React

Tags: reactjs

I was working on a project using ink for react and stumbled upon this error.

[image: Image showing error]

I have previously used callbacks with setState and am pretty clueless as to what is going on here.

I tried checking for other users with the same problem, but it felt one off so I'm here.

Any help regarding the same is appreciated.

Comment: You might find this article useful,  goes into detail about the use of callbacks and equivalent in useState hook. https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-usestate-callback/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It was possible to pass the 2nd argument as a callback to the `setState` function when using `class-based` components, but with the state setter function that the `useState` returns it's not the case, you can execute the code, that was previously executed in the callback, inside `useEffect` hook instead, it will have the same behavior as with callback.